# Native settings in app

Tags: ios, settings

Is it possible to use the actual or something similar to the settings bundle in app? What I mean is set up the bundle that you want to use in the native settings app, and use a separate one to handle more specific settings within the app?

Comment: Something like [In-App Settings Kit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)?

Comment: exactly like In-App Settings Kit. I'm downloading it now and will be trying it out shortly. Thank you sir

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, can you post this as an answer so i can select it as the best one? i'd rather not give it to people who are posting well after the fact

Comment: Don't worry about it. Accept the answer below, I don't need the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InAppSettingsKit lets you include the settings directly in your application. Check it out here:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/inappsettingskit